# TexMaker for MAC: Refer to specific part of my document in my editor that will show in the PDF Viewer

Tags: texmaker, mac

I am usig TeXmaker on my Mac.

When I reading the PDF I can simply press `cmd + right click` to see on PDF viewer to get to the same spot in the editor.

Can I somehow go the other way around? Click on my editor and the PDF viewer will show that passage in the center or something like that.

Comment: I don’t use TeXmaker but did you try using the same thing in the source window?

Comment: have you tried `cmd + RMB` in the internal PDF viewer? (RMB = right mouse button)

Comment: also: you can check in `Configure TeXmaker -> Shortcuts` which keybind is assigned to `Goto Source` & `Goto PDF` respectively

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>$</kbd> and it will do the trick and the PDF section will be highlighted.